# What are the unwritten rules of BCG.SE MtG Questions and Answers?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering, formatting, etiquette, hyperlinks

Following some comment bits on "[If a card is cloned...](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28362/if-a-card-becomes-cloned-while-another-text-modifying-effect-is-on-the-stack-wh)," I am curious as to any remaining style guidance, or norms, that a new arrival would want to be aware of? At the link, it was noted that it is the norm to only autocard the first appearance of a Card in the Answer/question combination. Justification was separately provided by highlighting the wikipedia style guide.

If a style guide doesn't exist for questions and answers here on bcg.se, with specific relation to things posted under the Magic the Gathering tag, what are the community norms?

Comment: Your situation's just a styling thing us in the MTG section have picked up (largely inspired by Wikipedia, as I see Jefromi noted), but you seem to be asking about all of our unwritten rules, or norms, across the whole site, without any particular scope (not just MTG questions, not just editing). That's a really big question, and not one I'm sure we could even have a satisfactory answer for - there's lots of siloed communities on this site who don't really know _or_ care what people do in other tags, let alone understand half the material in them for lack of having played the game in question.

Comment: @doppelgreener Fair point; I'm use to adhering to the style guide on wikipedia, the AP style guide, and Systems Engineering style guide. If there isn't a broad style guide, lets narrow it to just Magic the Gathering tag. Edited.

Comment: I think that what you are asking for here is almost by definition unanswerable. Norms and unwritten rules are generally convention and generalizations of behavior. Usually, people don't have a list of norms ready in their mind, but they notice when someone does not follow them, as I did in the comment you're referring to. Basically, I think that if you had asked this question yesterday, I wouldn't have thought to mention that you only link to each thing once, either in the context of MTG or in general.

Comment: I have updated [the tag wiki](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-the-gathering/info), here's a [shortcut to the revision history](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/2883/revisions). I added a new paragraph under "Linking to Card Images and Text". If anyone wants to edit it further, be my guest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an unwritten rule is identified and largely agreed upon, perhaps it should be written down?

In this case, adding one sentence to the existing tag description would suffice.

Comment: This was my initial expectation; I checked the tag info, prior to posting this question, for communal guidance relating to this tag.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - sounds great!  We can't be perfect, but should strive to continually improve.

Comment: This is great advice, but it does not appear to answer the question, "What are the unwritten rules?" I would upvote if it were a comment.